# Matching query with multiple values in Elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am trying to write a query, In which multiple values should get matched with the field.

In the example, I am trying to get results from all months with the matching field in the query. What I don't know is, how to write this query in dsl ?

```
months = [2,3,4]
client = Elasticsearch()
    s = Search(using=client, index="namco_revenuestream")
s = s.query("match", month_period=months)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) instead of `match` query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "month_period": [2,3,4]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Query using `match`**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "month_period": {
        "query": "2 3 4",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know this. But, I want to do this in s = s.query("match", month_period=months), in dsl.

Comment: Updated answer using match query.

Comment: No it's different. You are using array of values. I used all values, each separated by a space as a single string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
q1 = Q("terms", phone=items)
```